# MongoDB SUM returning 0 - Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have below query:

```
Machine.aggregate([{"$group":{_id:"$cluster",sum:{"$sum":"$cores"}}}]).exec(function(err, agg) {
            if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
            } else {

                res.json(agg);
            }
            });
```

Which returns:

```
[{"_id":"5","sum":0},{"_id":"","sum":0},{"_id":"4","sum":0},{"_id":"2","sum":0},{"_id":"3","sum":0},{"_id":"1","sum":0}]
```

Here is some sample data: (there is lots of documents)

```
[{"_id":"55d5dc40281077b6d8af1d9d","hostname":"1","domain":"domain","description":"VMWare ESXi 5","cluster":1,"type":"Physical","os":"EXSi","idc":"LH5","environment":"PROD-LH5","deviceclass":"host","cores":64,"memory":256,"mounts":[],"roles":["ESX-HOST"],"ipset":{"backnet":"10.83.48.30"},"frontnet":[],"created":"2015-09-10T13:51:06.062Z"},
```

Why is it returning 0 when the actual totals are in the hundreds, if not thousands?

Comment: Your "results" show "cluster" as a "string" in the grouped `_id` where the document is a plain `Double` value. Therefore I find it hard to believe you are really showing a true document and the most likely cause is that "cores" is in fact a "string" as well. Also the `err` would not be a `404` but a true "error" and therefore `500`. A `404` would be when the resulting array was empty.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - I am using a MEAN framework and thus have a model for my DB. Cores was indeed a String at first but I believe I have converted it both in the model and the actual DB - how do I check?

Comment: Nothing to do with "framework". Check the actual data in the mongodb shell. I think you will find your "imported" data to actually show a "string" for the "cores" field rather than what you claim. My point was basically that you "told us" the "cluster" field is not a string, but your aggregation result tells us otherwise. So that is a string as well.

Comment: Sample data from shell:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d5dc40281077b6d8af1c0d"), "hostname" : "p", "domain" : "domain", "description" : "VMWare ESXi 5", "cluster" : "3", "type" : "Physical", "os" : "EXSi", "idc" : "AMS", "environment" : "DR", "deviceclass" : "host", "cores" : 64, "memory" : "256", "frontnet" : [ ], "ipset" : { "backnet" : "10.63.31.103" }, "roles" : [ "ESX-HOST" ], "mounts" : [ ] }`

Comment: So it looks that cores is indeed a Number

Comment: @BlakesSeven - also kudos to your rep in such a short space of time in this field :)

Comment: Run `db.collection.find({ "cores": { "$type": 2 } })` and see what it returns. If nothing is a string then it returns nothing. Using whatever your collection name is in place of `collection` here of course. "machines?" as that is what mongoose is expecting.

Comment: `> db.Machines.find({ "cores": { "$type": 2 } })
>
`

Comment: Not sure I really "need the press" of "featured links" that I can now clearly see as well. Back to solving problems. We are making sure no strings are present and that you truly are posting the "real code" you are using with no alterations.

Comment: Okay, so if I run it direct in MongoDB (the aggregation), it returns the expected results. I will do some hunting in the framework to see where this issue is occurring. Thanks for you help so far

Comment: How is your mongoose model defined? I already said the "default" and "expected" collection name is "machines" in "lower case". Did you name it explicitly in the model? Do you perhaps have another collection actually called "machines" in lower case?

Comment: machines is the name in the MongoDB shell.  `Machine = mongoose.model('Machine'),` - is how it is defined in the controller.

Comment: noting the "case difference" from what you quote in comments earlier as `db.Machines.find({`. If that query worked then you in fact have two collections and thus the likely cause of the issue.

Comment: doh! just ran show collections and that is indeed the case

Comment: Yup. And the one that "mongoose" is picking ( the lower case one ) has "cores" as a string. And likely from an earlier data import. Use `.mogoose.model( 'Machines', schemaDef, "Machines" )` to use the fixed collection explicitly. And that's why the rep score, as I've seen it all before. Aggregation `$sum` to `0` always means "it's a string", and mongoose model naming misundertanding means you pick the wrong collection.

Comment: If you need more rep, you are welcome to mark this as the answer and I will mark it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cores" was not a number in the schema. I was using a different collection to the one that I thought, hence. the error.